# Small residual but wrong results

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method

When I use BiCGStab to solve a linear matrix system, I use the relative residual to exit the iteration and output the results. For calculating the relative residual I divide the norm of vector $r$ through the norm of vector $b$. Where $r$ is according to the definition of BiCGStab algorithm and $b$ is the right hand side of the matrix equation.

But even if I set the relative residual for convergency to 1e-8 the difference between calculated and exact results are quite big. When setting relative residual for convergency to 1e-14, I get good results.

The matrix systems I am solving have about 100k unknowns. A lot of entries in the result vector match the exact result. Only a few are off. But these few are enough to propagate the error.

Question: Is the relative residual really a good measure for convergency? Is this a normal behavior of the algorithm?

Comment: It appears that your system of equations is ill-conditioned, which is a common problem.  You need to find a different system of equations to solve.

Comment: Yes, the system of equations is ill-conditioned. I already use preconditioner like incomplete LU but still can observe the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Is 1e-8 and 1e-14 a *relative* or an *absolute* tolerance? You need to choose a tolerance that is small *relative to the norm of the right hand side*.

Comment: Also note that preconditioning changes the residual measure: BICGStab stops on $\|P(Ax-b)\|$ small, not $\|Ax-b\|$. The two may differ a lot, when $A$ is ill-conditioned.

Comment: 1e-8 and 1e-14 are relative tolerance. Is it possible to get the unpreconditioned residual without too much computation? But this is an interesting hint. Never thought about it, but you are right.

Comment: @vydesaster As far as I know there is no standard/smart way to get the unpreconditioned residual, apart from the obvious one of evaluating $Ax_k - b$. Now that I think of it, if at each step you compute $P(Aq_j)$ ($j=1,2,...,k$) in this order, in theory you could put to use the partial results in parentheses to compute the unpreconditioned residual in O(nk), since $x_k$ is a linear combination of the $q_j$. I have never seen it done this way, though. Maybe there is a good reason, such as instability.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will see if I can figure out a solution. Otherwise I have to set the preconditioned relative residual tolerance to a small value in order to achieve good results.